# document.body.onloadは以前の書き方？

Tags: javascript

**document.body.onloadはどういう位置づけの書き方でしょうか？**
・以前の書き方？
・現在でも通用する？？
・HTML  要素 の onload属性と関係している？
・[ドキュメント](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/Document/body)はどこかにあるでしょうか？

・何となくwindow.onloadを使用した方が良いとは思うのですが、違いはあるでしょうか？
・気になったので質問しました

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 現在でも通用する？

現在でも通用します。
ただ複数のイベントハンドラを使う時には、イベントリスナーを使った方がスマートだと思います。

> HTML 要素 の onload属性と関係している？

body要素（種類としてHTML要素ならその通り)のonload 属性

> ドキュメントはどこかにあるでしょうか？

例えば、これ[body 要素](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/HTML/Element/body)

> 何となくwindow.onloadを使用した方が良いとは思うのですが、違いはあるでしょうか？

違いはありません。

[body 要素](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/HTML/Element/body)のonload属性の説明で

> この要素はグローバル属性を持ちます。

とあるので、グローバル変数として[window](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/Window)のプロパティとしてぶら下がっているだけで、

この[window](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/Window)の説明を見ると、`window`自体のプロパティやイベントハンドラとしてはないのが分かります。

例えば、

```
<body onload="alert('test')">
```

のようにしてページを開いた後、
javascript コンソールウインドウで

```
window.onload === document.body.onload
```

とすると
`true`が返ることで確かめられます。
(Chrome だと`window.onload` の内容が

```
function onload(event) {
  alert('test')
}
```

になっていることが確認できる）

Comment: 「window.onload === document.body.onload」。試してみましたが確かにtrueになりました。「グローバル変数としてwindowのプロパティとしてぶら下がっているだけで、このwindowの説明を見ると、window自体のプロパティやイベントハンドラとしてはないのが分かります」。この回答を読んで勘違いしていたことに気が付きました。onloadは、windowではなく、GlobalEventHandlersのプロパティなんですね。だから、body 要素の「グローバル属性を持ちます」が適用される。なるほど、大変参考になりました

Comment: @re9  「onloadは、windowではなく‌​、GlobalEventHandlers‌​のプロパティ」私の言う意味は違います。HTMLにおけるjavascriptの大域変数は`window["onload"]`になっているというのが、「windowのプロパティとしてぶら下がっている」の意味です。あくまで`body`の属性であってそれが大域変数になっているという意味です。例えば、`onload` エンターと何もつけないで内容を確かめてみることができるので大域変数であるとわかると思います。

Comment: 「window自体のプロパティやイベントハンドラとしてはないのが分かります」についてですが、例えば「https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload」に掲載されている内容は、「windowオブジェクト」自体に所属しているわけではない、ということでしょうか？　所属ではなく継承しているだけ？

Comment: 繰り返しになりますが、`document.body.onload` だということです。 えっと、大域変数について調べて見て下さい。